# Tomcat 8.017 generation md5 with digest.bat

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, authentication, digest-authentication

I'm using digest authentication for my application with tomcat 8.0.17 and got strange behavior when i'm generate md5 password:

i'm run next command:
digest -a md5 restful:MyDigestRealm:restful
and got next output:
restful:MyDigestRealm:restful:**d1df53aca583cfe9a81b6b0d950dea45b55f35d404d0772de5af45773906002f$1$b2cdc5297fb7f1ea089b704cc4a0d828**

when i try run same command next time i got different md5 for example:
restful:MyDigestRealm:restful:**aee2438ec0d38ed70d5717b4348c5e55b568757f09ab5eeec69571c5833e2d59$1$de3055edb6f1cc2195e3bba976d00305**

Environment: win 8, java 8, tomcat 8.0.17

But on another laptop with configuration : win 7, java 7, tomcat 7.0.47
when i run the same command several times ( digest -a md5 restful:MyDigestRealm:restful ) i've got one output for all times:
restful:MyDigestRealm:restful:**26faed3eaa76b18ec9810155057863b8**

And one more: when i inserted md5 password generated with tomcat 7.0.47 into database on laptop with tomcat 8.0.17 digest authentication works good.
When i use password from tomcat 8.0.17 it doesn't works.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: any news on this? I am running into the same problem...

Comment: it turned out that my problem was a missing mysql-connector in the Tomcat libs, so it's probably unrelated to your problem.

Comment: no... unfortunately no news...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the salt length and encoding. Try this:

```
digest -a md5 -s 0 -e utf-8 restful:MyDigestRealm:restful
```

The salt length is needed in order to get consistent results on the same machine. The encoding is needed to get consistent results on difference machines.